# What is the difference between "double a[]" and "double *a" when passing arguments in c++ functions?

Tags: c++

What is the difference, if it exists, between "double a[]" and "double *a" when passing arguments in c++ functions? I mean, are those two functions bellow the same?

```
void do_somethingA (double a[], size_t size_a)
{
    // ... do something
}

void do_somethingB (double *a, size_t size_a)
{
    // ... do something
}

int main()
{
    double X[] = {1.,2.,3.,4.,5.};
    double *Y;
    Y = new double[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        Y[i] = (double) i;
    do_somethingA(X,5);
    do_somethingA(Y,5);
    do_somethingB(X,5);
    do_somethingB(Y,5);
    delete [] Y;
}
```

No error in the code above. I'm just curious about this and I couldn't find a way to "google" it, sorry.

I'm passing both static and dynamic arrays as arguments to functions from which one uses "double a[]" and the other uses "double *a" and everything compiles and executes fine. Is it just a matter of style?

Comment: it is actually the same. When you pass an array to a function as a parameter, what you're really passing in is the address of the first element of the array, that is synonymous with  a or a[0].

Comment: @blade not if you pass it by reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that context `double a[]` and `double *a` are defined to be absolutely, 100% identical. This is a C++ question but a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) is still relevant.

---

From the C++11 standard:

> 8.3.5
>
> After determining the type of each parameter, **any parameter of type
>   "array of T"** or "function returning T" is adjusted to be **"pointer to
>   T"** or "pointer to function returning T," respectively.

Comment: You can however pass reference to arrays which will at least keep the size  semantics.

Comment: Thanks, @cnicutar, specially for the _C FAQ_ reference! I'm choosing this answer because of the reference, but all answers have something to add to discussion. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, there is a difference.

To the reader, a function requiring `double a[]` is expecting an array.

A function requiring a `double * a`, is a pointer to a one or more `double` values.  There is some ambiguity as to whether the function will be operating on more than one contiguous `double`.  All the reader can assume is that *one* double, pointed to by the given pointer*, may be accessed;  the reader can't assume that an array of `double` is required.

See also the MISRA C and MISRA C++ coding guidelines.

Comment: I agree with you @ThomasMatthews. Semantically, it could help the comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays passed by value decay to pointers, so in your case `double a[]` (or even `double a[256]`) is just syntactic sugar for `double* a`. However, arrays are not pointers, and the difference appears when you pass arrays by reference. In that case, you can even deduce their size, such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t get_arr_size(T (&arr)[N]) // pass array by reference
{
    return N;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int* p = new int[256];
    std::cout << get_arr_size(arr) << std::endl; // displays 4
    // std::cout << get_arr_size(p) << std::endl; // does not compile, not the same as array
    delete[] p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @vsoftco! I liked your example, cause I could see a possible difference between static and dynamic arrays as arguments.